# Cruisecontrol.net with UCM Clearcase - How to?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, clearcase-ucm

I am trying to configure Cruisecontrol.net for UCM Clearcase for the first time. Following is the sourceControl tag in the ccnet.config file:

```
<sourcecontrol type="clearCase">
            <branch>123_India_Release</branch>  
            <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
            <viewName>admin_123_CRUISE</viewName>
            <viewPath>$(ViewDirectory)</viewPath>
            <useLabel>false</useLabel>
            <useBaseline>false</useBaseline>
            <executable>cleartool.exe</executable>
        </sourcecontrol>
```

I constantly receive the following error:

> ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Source control
>   operation failed: cleartool: Error: Not an object in a vob: "PATH TO
>   THE VIEW"

When I run cleartool from an arbitrary directory with the following parameters:

> cleartool.exe lshist -r -nco -branch "123_India_Release" -since
>   05-Dec-2012.14:38:18 -fmt

I get the same error. But if I change the working directory to $(ViewDirectory) before running cleartool, it runs fine.

How should I make Cruisecontrol.net run cleartool.exe from the $(ViewDirectory)?
I have already tried adding `<workingDirectory>$(ViewDirectory)</workingDirectory>` tag before `<executable>cleartool.exe</executable>` but it did not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**

As a workaround I have done the following:

```
            <exec>
                <executable>cleartool.exe</executable>
                <baseDirectory>d:\Workspace\123_India_Release\VOB</baseDirectory>
                <buildArgs>update -force</buildArgs>
                <buildTimeoutSeconds>6000</buildTimeoutSeconds>
            </exec>
```

I have added this to the **tasks** tag. I have configured an hourly trigger which does the following:

> 1) Update snapshot view
>
> 2) Build the VS 2010 solutions mentioned in the tasks tag.

The limitations are:

> 1) The trigger is hourly. I want it to be a commit based trigger.
>
> 2) This is a workaround

**EDIT 2:**

Further experimentation revealed that the **ccnet.exe** works fine. It does all that is needed. The issue is caused by the service **ccservice**.

I have stopped **ccservice** for now and started ccnet.exe. I plan to leave it running.

Answer (score 0):

The View directory isn't enough: you must specify a vob.

See for instance:

- "[clearfsimport: Error: Not an object in a vob: "\".](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21214748)" (as an illustratio of that error message)
- [this thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=196843) (or [this one](http://markmail.org/message/3tvibsq7ep5th2zk#query%3a+page:1+mid%3awkemk356vddegexf+state%3aresults)): "You have to specify explicitly the VOB(s) to check for modification set"

The path should looks like:

```
<viewPath>Drive:\path\to\view\vobname</viewPath>
```

If your `$(ViewDirectory)` already references `Drive:\path\to\view`, then you could use:

```
<viewPath>$(ViewDirectory)\vobname</viewPath>
```

Comment: The $(ViewDirectory) already is equal to $(ViewDirectory)\vobname. I have tried making $(ViewDirectory) one level up and one level down etc. But nothing worked. Cleartool works only if we change working directory to $(ViewDirectory).

Comment: @msiyer can you test and replace `$(ViewDirectory)` by the full path, to see if the issue persists?

Comment: @msiyer could you try the path in `<viewpath>` elements, as mentioned in the threads I reference? (instead of `<baseDirectory>`)

Comment: @msiyer darn it ;) Sorry to not be more helpful on this one.

Comment: VonC, funny thing - ccnet.exe works fine. It is the ccservice that is creating this trouble.

Comment: @msiyer interesting. Note that you have a list a potential issues with ccservice at http://build.sharpdevelop.net/ccnet/doc/CCNET/The%20Server%20Service%20Application.html or http://build.sharpdevelop.net/ccnet/doc/CCNET/FAQ.html.